# Unexplode (ungroup) cumulative dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas

COVID-19 Data set is available like this. As can be seen, each date is cumulative of all past dates. I want to capture only day's additions - kind of "ungroup by". I have this info in a Pandas dataframe. I tried using "explode" but that is not the right solution.

```
    Country       3/14/20  3/15/20  3/16/20  3/17/20  3/18/20  3/19/20  3/20/20  3/21/20  
    ___________________________________________________________________________________
    China          80977    81003    81033    81058    81102    81156    81250    81305    
    Italy          21157    24747    27980    31506    35713    41035    47021    53578    
    US             2727     3499     4632     6421     7783    13677     19100    25489        
    Spain          6391     7798     9942    11748    13910    17963     20410    25374         
    Germany        4585     5795     7272     9257    12327    15320     19848    22213         
    Iran           12729    13938    14991    16169    17361    18407    19644    20610       
    France         4496     4532     6683     7715     9124    10970     12758    14463        
    Korea, South   8086     8162     8236     8320     8413     8565     8652     8799     
    Switzerland    1359     2200     2200     2700     3028     4075     5294     6575        
    United Kingdom 1144     1145     1551     1960     2642     2716     4014     5067
```

The sample output what I want  is this - only cases added per day.

```
Country    3/14/20  3/15/20  3/16/20  3/17/20  3/18/20  3/19/20  3/20/20  3/21/20  
___________________________________________________________________________________
China          32       26      30       25       44        54       94       55             
Italy         .....
US            .....
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: is it `df.diff(axis=1)` or mayby `df.T.diff().T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), but first column is filled by missing values because not exist previous column in sample data:

```
#if necessary
#df = df.set_index('Country')
df = df.diff(axis=1)
print (df)
                3/14/20  3/15/20  3/16/20  3/17/20  3/18/20  3/19/20  3/20/20  \
Country                                                                         
China               NaN     26.0     30.0     25.0     44.0     54.0     94.0   
Italy               NaN   3590.0   3233.0   3526.0   4207.0   5322.0   5986.0   
US                  NaN    772.0   1133.0   1789.0   1362.0   5894.0   5423.0   
Spain               NaN   1407.0   2144.0   1806.0   2162.0   4053.0   2447.0   
Germany             NaN   1210.0   1477.0   1985.0   3070.0   2993.0   4528.0   
Iran                NaN   1209.0   1053.0   1178.0   1192.0   1046.0   1237.0   
France              NaN     36.0   2151.0   1032.0   1409.0   1846.0   1788.0   
Korea, South        NaN     76.0     74.0     84.0     93.0    152.0     87.0   
Switzerland         NaN    841.0      0.0    500.0    328.0   1047.0   1219.0   
United Kingdom      NaN      1.0    406.0    409.0    682.0     74.0   1298.0   

                3/21/20  
Country                  
China              55.0  
Italy            6557.0  
US               6389.0  
Spain            4964.0  
Germany          2365.0  
Iran              966.0  
France           1705.0  
Korea, South      147.0  
Switzerland      1281.0  
United Kingdom   1053.0
```